# How to modify the Title Bar text for SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Sometimes I keep multiple instances of SQL Server Management Studio 2005 open. I might have the dev database open in one, and the production database open in another. These appear in the Windows task bar with the text "Microsoft SQL Serve...", which means it's impossible to differentiate between them unless I open the window and scroll the Object Explorer up to see what server the window is actually connected to.

Is ther any way that I can get the window to display the server name first, and *then* the name of the application? Like "Dev-DB.database_name - Microsoft SQL Serve..." or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many ways to tackle this, 2 I can think of I have not actually tried but the suggestions may prove useful:

1. Multiple "virtual desktops" instead of relying on just one desktop, split the use of SSMS over one desktop each. There many be other benefits in doing this as well (but yes there may be downsides too). Windows 10 offers this this natively.
2. autohotkey (free open source) has an ability to rename title through its scripting language. You would also get the benefit os declaring different hotkeys as well. see: https://www.autohotkey.com/ [WinSetTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and [MS Windows: Change taskbar text](https://superuser.com/questions/406821/ms-windows-change-taskbar-text)